# Developer: Missing Privacy Policy‏ - Did not update in time

Tags: facebook, email, privacy, policy

I recieved two emails from facebook to put privacy policy link but I couldn't do it in time. I had over 8000 active users and now none can connect onto my forum. I guess they terminated the app? I did add the link onto my app but still it isn't working. I have looked around to see If anyone else went through the same. How do I contact Facebook and get this resolved.

Comment: Did you try accessing the application yourself? If possible could you provide the link for your application. And as per your contact request, you can revert back on the mail that you have received from Facebook (same mentioned [here](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/contact/)).

Answer (score 0):

> I guess they terminated the app?

Check your app dashboard – usually, as a first measure, your app gets put into sandbox mode.

Add the missing policy links, and then try taking it out of sandbox mode again.